# How to source a file only for a defined sudo user in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to source a file in .bashrc only for my user id when I sudo to the functional id. it should not be sourced when other user sudo in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add to the `.bashrc`

```
[[ -f .$(logname).bashrc ]] && source .$(logname).bashrc
```

and put your commands into the

```
.your_login.bashrc
```

If you don't have `logname` command can use

```
who am i | awk '{print $1}
```

instead of the `logname`